# .htaccess file doesn't work in subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, frameworks, subdomain

I need to help with my .htaccess files.

I am using my own PHP framework with same folder structure as PHP Phalcon has.

So it looks like:

- /

  - /app
  - /public

    - index.php ( Router )
    - **.htaccess** (second)
    - *..other files*
  - **.htaccess** (first)

### First .htaccess file:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteEngine On
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [NC]
</IfModule>
```

### Second .htaccess file:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteEngine On
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,NC]
</IfModule>
```

It works perfectly on websites, but when I move the whole project to subdomain, it doesn't work. Can someone tell me why? And what should I change?

I tried to look for similar questions, but no one has asked about the same problem.

Thanks for help.